# All Questions Area Empty When No Featured Questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

When clicking on the [questions tab](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions) it defaults to featured but if there are no featured questions it shows an empty space where the list should be.

Should the default behavior be to show a different sort if there are no featured questions?  Or perhaps some text explaining no featured questions available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh, this is a regression. That text is there for `/questions/tagged` but it got removed somehow for `/questions`.

I went ahead and improved it on the homepage, questions, and tagged views. Good catch.